# Does anti-realism say that what we can't know isn't true?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, truth, realism

Has anyone, in the history of philosophy, ever objected to anti-realism that then our thoughts aren't about anything except our own minds and such that supposing we believe we have contacted a "[shell](http://theosophy.wiki/en/Shell)" or "[elemental](http://theosophy.wiki/en/Elementals)" during an attempted ouija, due to e.g. gullibility and madness, the strange belief is *not false **if** it can't be shown to be*.

Comment: i imagine it's a daft question

Comment: the only thing that is even vaguely "personal" about it is how i explain the question in the title, with an absurd case. quit breaking the rules with your bad voting

Comment: how is the question "not answerable"? you should not be allowed to use this site

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. Beliefs need not be either true or false. Like truth, falsifiability is a condition of statements, not things.

Comment: Anti-realism says exactly that -- that what we can't verify is neither true nor false.  And anti-realists themselves have taken up your claim even when it was not an objection.  Quite a number of anti-realisms and related positions, for example mentalist pantheists and modal 'realists', have insisted that all imagined things and experiences are just as real as the external environment -- just in a different way.  If there is no (trustworthy) reality, one can be in conflict with conventional knowledge, but not wrong.  But other than unwinding the literal definition, what is the question?

Comment: can you please rephrase the q in a less nutty form?

Comment: @mobileink not sure why that would be a desirable change, it's meant to be stupid